# Unnest a JSON array in as multiple rows - BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like this

```
| id | title    |  metadata                                      |
| 1  | apples   | [{"tags": [200,211], "categories": [313,412]}] |
| 2  | oranges  | [{"tags": [311,112], "categories": [616,712]}] |
```

I want to unnest the metadata so the results is one row per tag

```
| id | title     |  tag |
| 1  | apples    |  200  | 
| 1  | apples    |  212  |
| 2  | oranges   |  313  |  
| 2  | oranges   |  112  |
```

I know I need to use [JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_query_array) to and UNNEST, but since there is another array nested inside JSON I'm a bit confused as to how these should interact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * except(metadata) from data,
unnest(split(trim(json_extract(trim(metadata, '[]'), '$.tags'), '[]'))) tag
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I believe this will work. However, when I add correct table to the first line e.g. "select * except(metadata) from ` project.data.table`" I get an error "Expected end of input but got keyword UNNEST"

Comment: make sure you don't miss comma after table name and make sure you have backticks around your table name. try again and let me know

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: @mikhal ah yes of course, thank you so much!